# What is currently the highest slew rate of any available op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, high-speed, slew-rate

Also, how is there a theoretical/practical upper limit to slew rates?
Suppose a customer wanted an extreme high speed op amp with a slew rate of, say, 5 Volts per femtosecond(which would translate to 5GV/μs)? Would that even be possible with a purely electronic op amp or would optics be required.

Comment: An odd question. What do you need it for? Or is it homework? Perhaps the highest available slew rates costs a hundred thousand dollars, is it still useful for you?

Comment: Let me consult the Guinness Book of Analog Electronics and get back to you.

Comment: How would optics generate a rapid voltage change?

Comment: 500MHz is the max I have seen.  What current do you expect into 1pF at this rate, then you can determine the source impedance or current per picofarad.  Ic=CdV/dt = 1e-12*5e9 * 1e6 = 60e3 Amps 60 thousand amps into 1 picofarad. How about an EMP? Sorry no negative feedback MR X.  For EO parts they are not Op AMPs but GaAs semiconductors.

Comment: There are 6.5 GHz fully-differential amps like the [LMH5401](http://www.ti.com/product/LMH5401-SP) or [ADL5569](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adl5569.html) with up to 24 kV/µs.

Comment: Perhaps this is more a solid state physics question than purely an electronics question. Because yes, I am being 100% theoretical.

Comment: Go on digikey and do a search

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of an odd question. According to Digikey the fastest opamp slew rate is currently 24V/ns. ADL5569

But keep in mind the context - opamps are intended to have well-controlled, low-noise, linear outputs. This means that their slew rates are always "held back" to allow for good stability.

If you use digital circuits, like fast logic gates, the maximum slew rate is far higher. For example, I have worked with digital logic that has a slew rate of about 100V/ns.

Ultimately, the slew rate will be limited by the RLC characteristics of your circuit. And that is totally dependent on what you are trying to use the circuit for.